# HTML to WordPress 3 process

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am in the process of learning WordPress 3 and have a 5 page HTML website with whole header, sidebar, content and footer, that I would like to convert into a WordPress theme.

What is the best way to do this?

Any useful online tutorials that people recommend would also be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Official documentation here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page
And topic on themes development: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development
Multiple posts in one page generation core code: http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Of course you could take a look to code of existing themes, well, that was easier for me this way...